# Can't import TensorFlow in Spyder but can be imported in cmd

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, anaconda

Importing TensorFlow was working completely fine in Spyder and all of a sudden stopped working. The following was the error that was the error reported.

import tensorflow
  Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<ipython-input-1-a649b509054f>", line 1, in <module>
  import tensorflow

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
  from tensorflow.python import *

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 100, in <module>
  from tensorflow.python.platform import app

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 23, in <module>
  from tensorflow.python.platform import flags

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/flags.py", line 25, in <module>
  _global_parser = _argparse.ArgumentParser()

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1586, in __init__
  prog = _os.path.basename(_sys.argv[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of a problem usually occurs when Spyder gets upgraded. Turns out there was some bug in Spyder 3.1 version and there was an auto upgrade which caused the import to stop working. I just downgraded to version 3.0 from Anaconda Navigator and things seem to be working fine.

[This](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3987) link discusses the same in sufficient detail.